# Rendering a compiled template from controller in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to render some html to the DOM that has AngularJS directives

**HTML**

```
<a ng-click="doThing()">hello 2015</a>
```

Except due to constraints in my application, I have to add it to the view from the controller. I am attempting to do this using the `$compile` service.

**Controller.js**

```
let html = '<a ng-click="doThing()">hello 2015</a>';

const compiledTemplate = $compile(html)($scope);

document.getElementById('wrapper').innerHTML = compiledTemplate[0].innerHTML;

$scope.doThing = function(){

    console.log('it worked!');
}
```

**View.html**

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

This renders the correct HTML but the directives dont work. Clicking on the link does not fire the `doThing()` function.

How can I compile and render a string representation of an AngularJS template such that all angular directives are functional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you're just copying the raw HTML string out of the compiled directive - none of the bindings are copied, just the string.

Best to call `$compile()` with a HTML element instead of with an HTML string, like this:

```
//find the wrapper DOM element
const directiveTarget = document.getElementById('wrapper');

//put the raw HTML into it
directiveTarget.innerHTML = '<a ng-click="doThing()">hello 2015</a>';

//get the angularjs-friendly version of the element
const directiveElement = angular.element(directiveTarget);

//initialise AngularJS bindings
const compiledTemplate = $compile(directiveElement)($scope);
```

Comment: this was the solution. I dont know why I thought compiling the raw html would work. thank you!

Comment: Any time. Good luck with your project!